# Installing Certificate for VPN and APPs

Tags: android, certificate

I'm trying to ask the user to install a certificate, however I only wanted to do it on VPN and apps credential use and not Wi-Fi.

The dialog shows both options which the user can choose like it is shown in  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l17pw9psm1uojnc/Screenshot%202017-08-23%2010.44.43.png?dl=0)

So far I could not find any option that would force the VPN and apps option to only show up.

I'm calling the certificate installation like this:

```
 Intent clientCertInstall = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
 clientCertInstall.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, __CERT_ENCODING__);
 clientCertInstall.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, __NAME__);
 activity.startActivityForResult(clientCertInstall, __CODE__);
```

Additionally, If the user installs the certificate, the app will receive the information onActivityResult, but the intent will be null and the result code -1, telling me nothing about if the user choosed WIFI or VPN and apps.

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Finally, if the user installs the certificate via Wi-Fi I could not find it under keystore aliases like below:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
Eumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
       String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
       X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
       BigInteger localCertSerialNumber = cert.getSerialNumber();
       String localIssuerDN = cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();

       BigInteger serial = new BigInteger(currentCertificateSerial);
       if (installedCertSerialNumber.compareTo(localCertSerialNumber) == 0 && installedCertIssuerDn.equals(localIssuerDN)) {
           //Should reach here but it does not when user installs certificate via Wi-Fi
       }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet?

Comment: No, not yet, until now I could not find anything that can help me